# What equations are needed to describe how two bodies interact?

Tags: orbital-motion

For a small project I am thinking about making a 2D game in which there are two planets, each of a random size, and when you run the game it will show how those planets interact due to gravity. I'm not that experienced with physics, so my question is: What equations are needed to accomplish this?

Note: I am not asking how to represent this in a game, I'm asking what formulas describe it in real life.

Comment: Depends heavily on which type of interaction you want to show. There's the basic law of gravitation and the derived equations of orbital motion, time period of revolution and so on.

Comment: @Aniket I'm more interested in the basic laws of gravitation and equations of orbital motion. Although, so far in my research orbital motion has only been about rockets and satellites, not two planetary bodies.

Comment: You need to check the following two links at http://www.physicsclassroom.com/calcpad/circgrav and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion.... Hope this helps. BTW Kepler's Law is also important. I missed it out earlier.

Comment: @Aniket Kepler is built in to Newton's law of gravity, so you don't have to add it.

Comment: @garyp You're right. But the laws are different. That's what I pointed out.

Comment: @Aniket Yes, but the OP is creating a simulation.  There's no need to even *mention* the word Kepler, and since the OP is a self-described novice, bringing up superfluous information could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple simulation you just need two equations that can be combined into one:

Newton's law of universal gravitation:
$$F=\frac{G\,m_1\,m_2}{r^2}$$

And Newton's second law:

$$F=m\,a$$

So the final combined equation would be:

$$a_1=\frac{G\,m_2}{r^2}$$

Or if your planets have positions $p_1$ and $p_2$ the vector equation would be:

$$m_1\frac{d^2p_1}{dt^2}=-m_2\frac{d^2p_1}{dt^2}=G\,m_1\,m_2\,\frac{p_2-p_1}{|p_2-p_1|^3}$$

Depending on how you do your integration it's likely that your orbits will be unstable. If you'd like your orbits to be stable, then you should use orbital equations that are already integrated and just follow those equations.

One advantage of doing the integration numerically is then you can include more bodies:

$$\frac{d^2p_i}{dt^2}=G\sum_{j\neq i}m_j\,\frac{p_j-p_i}{|p_j-p_i|^3}$$

To use this acceleration one possibly way to integrate would be to use the [Leapfrog Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) Here rather than keeping track of velocity you keep track of the last two positions:

$$p_{next}=2 p_{current}-p_{prev}+\Delta t^2\,\frac{d^2p}{dt^2}$$

So putting it all together in component form:

$$f=\frac{\Delta t^2\,G}{\left((p_{1x}-p_{2x})^2+(p_{1y}-p_{2y})^2+(p_{1z}-p_{2z})^2\right)^\frac32}$$
$$p_{1xNew}=2p_{1x}-p_{1xPrev}+f\,m_2(p_{2x}-p_{1x})$$
$$p_{2xNew}=2p_{2x}-p_{2xPrev}+f\,m_1(p_{1x}-p_{2x})$$
$$p_{1yNew}=2p_{1y}-p_{1yPrev}+f\,m_2(p_{2y}-p_{1y})$$
$$p_{2yNew}=2p_{2y}-p_{2yPrev}+f\,m_1(p_{1y}-p_{2y})$$
$$p_{1zNew}=2p_{1z}-p_{1zPrev}+f\,m_2(p_{2z}-p_{1z})$$
$$p_{2zNew}=2p_{2z}-p_{2zPrev}+f\,m_1(p_{1z}-p_{2z})$$

If you just want to do 2d you can ignore all the z coordinates.

Comment: So with your equation I can now solve for the acceleration of the two bodies, but what dictates in which direction they go? Would that be your vector equation?

Comment: You have to start with an initial position and velocity, or if you're using [Leapfrog integration] two potions a time step apart. I would recommend the second option, and I'll add it to my answer. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration)

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question. Yeah, that's the vector equation. The force is towards the other object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to all of this. Am I correct in that the vector equation will give me an angle? And also, am I correct in assuming that p1 is the x coordinate of a planet and p2 is the y coordinate? Or do they represent different planets location?

Comment: @TreFox $p_1$ is the vector position of planet 1. I've added the component equations to simulate 2 bodies in 3D.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the acceleration formula for n amount of bodies?

Comment: @TreFox that's the formula that has the summation sign in it. It's a vector equation, so to use it in a program, you'd have to expand it like I did for the two body equations.